# What is causing a Hibernate SQL query exception?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts, tomcat5.5

Hi all and sorry in advance for this post but I've spent way too much time going around in circles so I'm hoping someone could shed a light on it here for me.
I updated a webapp on Tomcat and I'm getting the following error which didn't exist on the previous version. Though I am quite confident that the part of code I modifed isn't to blame as I have tested the app on two different dev servers.

```
The production server is configured thus: CentOS 5.4 virtual server with tomcat 5.5.23 running mysql 5.0.77.
The two dev servers are: Windows XP SP2 running tomcat 5.5.23 with mysql 5.1.49
                         Mac OSX 10.6.6 Running tomcat 6 with mysql 5.1.51
```

The application was developed using struts (1.1 as far as I can gather) with hibernate 3 as the peristence layer. It only fails on the production server for some reason I can't fathom. I'd like to draw your attention to the ***java.sql.SQLException*** near the bottom. After some long searching I found [this](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-10753.html) but because it was posted years ago (about 1 year before development started on this app I'm sure Hibernate has evolved from that version. as I can't find a way of implementing his solution. I use Eclipse Helios as an IDE.
Thanks in advance for taking your time to read this, to all who manage to reply.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at fr.company.action.login.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:219)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at fr.company.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:37)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:113)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)


javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at fr.company.action.login.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:219)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at fr.company.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:37)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:113)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at fr.company.dao.GenericDAO.findOne(GenericDAO.java:204)
 at fr.company.dao.UserDAO.findOneUser(UserDAO.java:146)
 at fr.company.service.UserPeer.logUser(UserPeer.java:72)
 at fr.company.action.login.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:127)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at fr.company.util.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:37)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:113)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:65)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2153)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2029)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2024)
 at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:369)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:153)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1128)
 at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
 at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:749)
 at fr.company.dao.GenericDAO.findOne(GenericDAO.java:198)
 ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'user0_1_.poloSize' in 'field list'
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2994)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:936)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1030)
 at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1669)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2150)
 ... 35 more
```

Comment: run with `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` and give us the shown query (in the logs or console), and also give the entity mapping

Comment: The property was already added. However I can get eclipse to output the SQL queries. Not that it matters because there are no dev tools on the production server which is where the issue arises. The dev servers are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core error message says:

```
Unknown column 'user0_1_.poloSize' in 'field list'
```

As you say

> It only fails on the production server

could it be possible that the column indicated above is missing from your production DB (while present in the DB(s) used for dev/integration testing)?

Comment: this is part of SQL that was generated by hibernate. most probably it is mapping / configuration issue.

Comment: The column is required. I'm not the developer. I'm just troubleshooting code. Also the updated app works fine on the development servers

Comment: @Andrey, may be... with this amount of information, we are only making educated guesses :-(

Comment: I went and Painfully inspected the database. It would seem  someone has been arsing around on it. Thanks. 10 hours faffing around only to be caught out by that. :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cause of your problem is here..:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'user0_1_.poloSize' in 'field list'
>    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)

Comment: I know. I said as much in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

something is with your HQL. try to add to `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

and add SQL dump to post (and HQL)

Comment: I only get this exception on the remote production server. The dev servers don't have the same issue with the app. Not to mention there are no dev tools on the production server. and I honestly am versed in hibernate but I will try and find a way of getting you the SQLdump